# how to reverse a string of type char *?

Tags: c, reverse, undefined-behavior, string-literals, function-definition

I am using the `reverse` function.

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i, j;
    char c;
 
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i]; 
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
```

If I pass a string of type `char a[] = "abcd"` then I get on the output `dcba`.

But if I pass `char *a = "abcd"` the I get `bus error`.

Can I somehow reverse the string exactly of type `char *`?

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char s[]);

int main() {
    char a* = "abcd";
    reverse(a);
    printf("%s", a);
}

void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i, j;
    char c;
 
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) { 
        c = s[i]; 
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c; 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s?rq=1

Comment: @Andrey You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Comment: May I suggest `void revprint(const char *s) { for (size_t i = strlen(s); i-- > 0; ) putchar(s[i]); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no strings of type `char *`. A string is a sequence of characters terminated with the zero-character `'\0'`.

In this declaration (that has a typo `char a* = "abcd";`)

```
char *a = "abcd";
```

there is declared a pointer to a string literal. The string literal itself has the type `char[5]`. But used as an initializer expression it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *`.

And you are trying to change the string literal pointed to by the pointer within the function `reverse`.

However you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

What you could do is to create a new string that will store characters of the source string literal in the reverse order.

For example

```
char * reverse_copy( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char *t = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( t != NULL )
    {
        t += n;
        *t = '\0';

        while ( *s ) *--t = *s++;
    }

    return t;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
char *s = "abcd";
char *p = reverse_copy( s );
if ( p != NULL ) puts( p );
free( p );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *reverse_copy( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char *t = malloc( n + 1 );

    if (t != NULL)
    {
        t += n;
        *t = '\0';

        while (*s) *--t = *s++;
    }

    return t;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "abcd";

    char *p = reverse_copy( s );
    if (p != NULL) puts( p );

    free( p );
}
```

The program output is

```
dcba
```

Comment: does not work: free(): invalid pointer. if I remove free it will work, but there will be memory leaks.

Comment: @Andrey I am sorry. There was a typo. See the updated function.

Answer (score 1):

Your reverse function is ok. The problem is that you instantiated you string as a literal by doing so:
`char *a = "abcd";` (it's '*a' not 'a*' btw)

You cannot modify string literals.
To test your function you could do so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char s[]);

int main(){
    char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    if (a == NULL)
        return 1;
    a[0] = 'a';
    a[1] = 'b';
    a[2] = 'c';
    a[3] = 'd';
    a[4] = '\0';
    reverse(a);
    printf("%s", a);
    free(a);
}

void reverse(char s[]){
     int i, j;
     char c;

     for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i<j; i++, j--) {
         c = s[i];
         s[i] = s[j];
         s[j] = c;
     }
}
```